# Why the fact that the $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E_{m})=0$ implies this $ m(E_n)< \epsilon $?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a really basic question that I believe may seem trivial to most of you, but I graduated in physics and am currently trying to get my head around some measure theory. Since the question involve just a part of the whole problem, I will paraphrase just this part.

...Let $E_m$ be a decreasing sequence of sets in a sigma algebra R, such that
$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(E_m)=0 $

Thus, given an $\epsilon > 0 $ , there exists a number $n$ such that       $ m(E_n)< \epsilon $.

Can someone tell me why the former implies the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of "$\lim_{n \to \infty} m(E_n) = 0$", we mean "given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $|m(E_n)| < \epsilon$". This is the definition of the limit. Note in this case that since $(m(E_n))$ is a decreasing sequence (in $n$), you only need to find *some* $N$ such that $m(E_N) < \epsilon$, and then you know that for all $n \ge N$ we have $m(E_n) \le m(E_N) < \epsilon$, hence the result follows.

Note that if the limit in general were $L$ instead of $0$, then we replace "$|m(E_n)| = |m(E_n) - 0|$" by "$|m(E_n) - L|$". When the limit point is $0$, we can drop the modulus bars, since we know that $m(A) \ge 0$ for every set $A$, by definition of a measure $m$. However, we can't do this for a general limit $L$. Anyway, that's just some extra information, but hopefully it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation, just found this forum and I love what you guys are doing here... God bless you...

Comment: No problem! I'm at university myself, and so I know from recent experience that when you start a topic, some of the things that are "simple" are only simple when you know them!

Comment: Yeah, it is indeed so. I of course knew the definition of the limit, but just thought it has to do something with the properties of a measure. It will help a lot now that I know where it comes from... Thank you one more time